# I run the MCMC for SIR model code on my R software but there is no output until now

Tags: r

I tried to run code from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MultiBD/vignettes/SIR-MCMC.pdf on my R software - they are still running but no output until now but I can run the following code on an online R compiler. This is the codes:

```
library(MultiBD)
data(Eyam)
Eyam

loglik_sir <- function(param, data) {
  alpha <- exp(param[1]) # Rates must be non-negative
  beta <- exp(param[2])
  # Set-up SIR model
  drates1 <- function(a, b) { 0 }
  brates2 <- function(a, b) { 0 }
  drates2 <- function(a, b) { alpha * b }
  trans12 <- function(a, b) { beta * a * b }
  sum(sapply(1:(nrow(data) - 1), # Sum across all time steps k
             function(k) {
               log(
                 dbd_prob( # Compute the transition probability matrix
                   t = data$time[k + 1] - data$time[k], # Time increment
                   a0 = data$S[k], b0 = data$I[k], # From: S(t_k), I(t_k)
                   drates1, brates2, drates2, trans12,
                   a = data$S[k + 1], B = data$S[k] + data$I[k] - data$S[k + 1],
                   computeMode = 4, nblocks = 80 # Compute using 4 threads
                 )[1, data$I[k + 1] + 1] # To: S(t_(k+1)), I(t_(k+1))
               )
              }))
}

logprior <- function(param) {
  log_alpha <- param[1]
  log_beta <- param[2]
  dnorm(log_alpha, mean = 0, sd = 100, log = TRUE) +
    dnorm(log_beta, mean = 0, sd = 100, log = TRUE)
}

library(MCMCpack)
alpha0 <- 3.39
beta0 <- 0.0212
post_sample <- MCMCmetrop1R(fun = function(param) { loglik_sir(param, Eyam) + logprior(param) 
}, theta.init = log(c(alpha0, beta0)), mcmc = 500, burnin = 100)

plot(as.vector(post_sample[,1]), type = "l", xlab = "Iteration", ylab = 
expression(log(alpha)))
plot(as.vector(post_sample[,2]), type = "l", xlab = "Iteration", ylab = expression(log(beta)))

library(ggplot2)
x = as.vector(post_sample[,1])
y = as.vector(post_sample[,2])
df <- data.frame(x, y)
ggplot(df,aes(x = x,y = y)) +
  stat_density2d(aes(fill = ..level..), geom = "polygon", h = 0.26) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "grey85", high = "grey35", guide = FALSE) +
  xlab(expression(log(alpha))) +
  ylab(expression(log(beta)))

quantile(exp(post_sample[,1]), probs = c(0.025,0.975))
quantile(exp(post_sample[,2]), probs = c(0.025,0.975))
```

I realize that this is the part of the codes that took long time to run but produce no output :

```
post_sample <- MCMCmetrop1R(fun = function(param) { loglik_sir(param, Eyam) + logprior(param)},
theta.init = log(c(alpha0, beta0)), mcmc = 500, burnin = 100)
```

I think my R software is the problem but what is it?

Comment: Try reducing the `mcmc` and `burnin` to say 50 or less and run again. You will get know whether the problem is in your R software or nor.

Comment: I did mcmc = 50 and burnin = 10. They are still running but no output. It has been 10+ mins